# How to fix issue "EFI variables are not supported on this system"?

Tags: debian, boot, uefi

How to fix issue "EFI variables are not supported on this system."?

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
```

Debian11 installed in UEFI mode, but something wrong with boot stage, and system always boots into Legacy bios mode.(despite in boot menu set UEFI mode)

Edit: blkid output

```
sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL_FATBOOT="BOOT" LABEL="BOOT" UUID="2F1D-01E6" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="c906677e-c2c2-42b5-b818-f0b19c046e95"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="swap" UUID="1274a782-676a-41b0-8509-92f73bd675c3" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="4a555697-e713-400d-ae9e-613d028c7893"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="root" UUID="13503165-9c5f-498d-ab5f-0c13f11cbaa6" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="5484dedd-6adf-45af-b7b0-ba105d14528b"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="home" UUID="93c98828-5fb8-4c0e-b6bf-de8d13a9d22e" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ae15bbdb-4e29-4dfa-aa99-b39e5377a098"
```

Comment: Boot live installer flash drive in UEFI boot mode & add Boot-Repair. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO (unless 21.10)
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I tried first to reinstall GRUB based on this [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall) steps, I booted from LiveUSB in UEFI mode, installed efibootmgr, from chroot run `# apt remove grub-pc`(return it not installed) `# apt install --reinstall grub-efi` `# grub-install /dev/sda` `# update-grub`,exit, rebooted, but not help, debian still boots in Legacy mode.  Bootinfo [summary](https://pastebin.com/raw/NbyYUxWt).

Comment: Are you running old copy of Bootinfoscript? I also do not see any reference to UEFI, so did you boot in BIOS mode? Report as is, did not show anything unusual other than grub in MBR with gpt drive. Normally BIOS installs of grub require a 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag for grub to work correctly in BIOS mode. Boot of installed system typically requires UEFI boot on, or legacy/CSM/BIOS off in UEFI settings. And boot of flash drive requires UEFI:XXX option regardless of default settings for installed ssytem.

Comment: The Bootinfoscript installed via Package Manager, the latest vers there is 0.78-3. Yes, system still boots in legacy BIOS mode, despite in the boot menu set UEFI mode. Grub-PC installed incorrectly, on /dev/sda3 partition (root).

Comment: Since you have gpt, you must create a bios_grub partition for the BIOS version of grub. And you always install grub2's grub-pc to a drive like sda, never to a partition like sda3. I have been using gpt for about 10 years. And when converting from BIOS to UEFI, I would make first two partitions the ESP, then a bios_grub, so I could easily reinstall the different version of grub. Its grub-pc for BIOS and grub-efi-amd64 for UEFI.

Comment: I have 500 MiB /boot/efi partition on sda1.
How I can split/resize it to make a separate bios_grub partition? and its size?

Comment: Just have to shrink using gparted on live installer by several MB, probably 4MB. You want to create a 1MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag, but partitions may need space before & after. Then you should be able to install grub in BIOS mode to sda  & have it boot in BIOS mode. But still do not understand why UEFI does not work. I would keep ESP, so in future you can try again for UEFI boot.

Comment: It looks, that for some reason, the system can not create efi directory and subdir for EFI (`/sys/firmware/efi/vars`), even though I tried to install efibootmgr from chroot, but changes seems were not saved after reboot.

Comment: What brand/model system? Have you updated UEFI firmware to latest available for your model? You said you have an ESP?  the /sys/firmware/efi/vars is in / (root) not in ESP.

Comment: Dell Inspiron 3542, yes BIOS updated to latest version. The above path is in root directory, but I have `/sys/firmware`, as debian was installed in Legacy BIOS mode.

Comment: Did you follow this? https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Dell/Inspiron%20i15-3542-A30

Comment: No, not that particular guide, just common steps. I have no problem with drivers, only with UEFI. I followed that [link](https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall), but I don't know how to make boot DebianLive USB with the kernel option "efi=runtime". Using rescue mode of Debian installer is difficult and less convenient for that.

Comment: Ok, tried reinstall grub-efi booting from LiveCD(USB) and use chroot, the process finished without errors. Rebooted, but no changes, system boots into Legacy Bios mode. [Logfile](https://pastebin.com/raw/z1tieimb)

Comment: How you boot both install media & repair media UEFI or BIOS is how it normally repairs. difficult to convert unless booted into your install & ESP, & other system partitions are correctly mounted. UEFI chroot, must include ESP - efi system partition
http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380

Answer (score 1):

It seems your system prefers a legacy bootloader if it can find one.

If so, and there is no way to change this preference in BIOS settings, then the answer could be to actively destroy the legacy boot code that has been placed into block #0 of the system disk.

Assuming your system disk is `/dev/sda`, this should do it:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=446 count=1
```

This should make `/dev/sda` unbootable in the legacy BIOS sense, leaving only UEFI bootloader(s) if any are present on the disk.

If the system then fails to boot altogether, you may need to boot from external media, e.g. from Debian 11 installation media in rescue mode. When you do so, **make sure you choose to boot the external media in UEFI mode too**. If the external media is booted in legacy mode, the run-time interface to UEFI firmware settings will be disabled, and the UEFI bootloader installation process will fail.

If you need to reinstall the UEFI version of the GRUB bootloader, you may want to use a command line like this when chrooted into your installed system:

```
grub-install --force-extra-removable --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sda
```

If your system is supposed to use Secure Boot, add the `--uefi-secure-boot` option.

The `--force-extra-removable` option sets up an extra copy of the bootloader at `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` which is normally used on UEFI-bootable removable disks, and may be helpful if your system has a buggy implementation of UEFI.

The removable-media bootloader location can also be set up without access to the UEFI firmware settings, so in theory it should succeed even if the rescue boot has actually started in legacy mode. If this allows you to make the system boot from its own disk in UEFI mode, you should then be able to use `efibootmgr` to try and complete the UEFI bootloader registration process once the system is running in UEFI mode.

Comment: If you zero out the MBR, you erase partition table. If BIOS/MBR system, you just erased his system. IF gpt which it should be unless also booting Windows in old BIOS mode, then it may be recoverable with gdisk.

Comment: @oldfred the command I gave him only the first part of the MBR: the part where the boot code lives. The partition table is just the last 66 bytes of the block #0.

Comment: You are correct. And answer is good. Just would like to confirm configuration. If no ESP, then that may be the issue.

Comment: @telcoM I reinstalled grub with command `grub-install --force-extra-removable --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sda`, still boots in Legacy Bios mode. [bootinfo](https://pastebin.com/raw/d5QwXnBS)

Comment: You seem to have a fully valid ESP, including the alternate/removable media boot path, so double-check your BIOS settings, just in case there is something boot-related you missed.  If that does not help, it seems your BIOS prefers to boot in legacy mode unless it sees absolutely nothing bootable in that mode, so you'll need to destroy the legacy MBR boot code the way I suggested earlier. After that, you may need to go into the boot order settings and re-select the disk to boot from, since UEFI style might require a boot entry that is different from the legacy style.

Comment: And if that fails too, the Legacy mode will not be available anymore? Does UEFI allow boot external USB hard drives with other linux distro that was installed in BIOS mode?

Comment: UEFI does allow that if legacy compatibility is enabled, and your system seems to prefer booting in legacy mode if it sees anything legacy-bootable anyway, so as long as you have some legacy-style external boot media it should be no problem.

Comment: I destroed 446 bytes MBR boot code on /dev/sda: still not help. Now system boots only from external media. So I need to recover that boot record code from backup. Strange that system can boots from LiveUSB UEFI mode, but fails boots from hard disk. EFI v2.31 by American Megatrends, what the ugly utility.

Comment: The boot order list in BIOS settings might have separate entries for “boot this disk in BIOS mode” and “boot this disk in UEFI mode”. Try selecting the HDD for boot just as if it was a USB stick or other removable disk. If it boots, try ‘sudo efibootmgr -v’. If your BIOS includes an option to disable Secure Boot, try that too. EFI 2.31 seems like it might be one of the earlier implementations so it might be quirky.

Comment: there are no such entries in this BIOS, its sort of minimalistic [pic1](https://i.postimg.cc/QtJmQQSR/IMG-20211231-014508977.jpg),[pic2](https://i.postimg.cc/D05CTrXq/IMG-20211231-014256427-BURST000-COVER.jpg) What's not clear, why system can boot in UEFI mode from USB drive,  but fails boot from hard disk. Something wrong with installation on hdd?

Comment: Have you tried those two "UEFI OS" boot options in your second picture? What happens if you try them? Try setting "Fast Boot" in your first picture to "Disabled". You also have the "File browser Add boot option" - with it, you should be able to select the disk/ESP partition and the `\EFI\debian\grubx64.efi` file inside it, and give a human-readable description for it.

Comment: yes, I tried with "Fast Boot" disabled too. With USB drive attached, I added  boot option with path `/efi/Debian/grubx64.efi `,  saved it in the first place in boot order, still not help. In pure UEFI mode system not boots at all, no matter of Boot Options priorities, include [UEFI OS] boot options. While boot, it return "No bootable devices.."